# Using docker with running process

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I've created this docker file which works for

```
FROM debian:9

ENV CF_CLI_VERSION "6.21.1"


# Install prerequisites
RUN ln -s /lib/ /lib64 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y 


 RUN curl -L "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=${CF_CLI_VERSION}" | tar -zx -C /usr/local/bin
```

And it works as expected, now I run it like following

```
docker run -i -t cf-cli cf -v
```

and I see the version

Now every command which I want to run is something like

`docker run -i -t cf-cli cf -something`

my question is how can I enter into container and do ls etc without every-time doing

`docker run -i -t cf-cli` ...

I want to enter to the container like you enter to machine.

Comment: If you can download, untar, and directly run a CLI tool, what do you need Docker for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Run the container in background:

```
docke run -d --name myapp dockerimage
```

**Step2:**

Exec into the containr myapp:

```
docker exec -it myapp bash
```

run any commands inside as u wish

Comment: If the docker image is as the question, the first step should have a command to keep the container from being terminated (e.g. `bash`)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). You'll probably want something like `docker exec -it containername bash` depending on the shell installed in the container.

Comment: HI, how can I find the container name ? I've the image name and the image id

Comment: @JhonD by containername I mean the name/id of the image when you build it. You can specify a name when you build with `docker -t name .`.

Comment: when I build it I did it like `docker build -t cf-cli .`

Comment: and when I run  `docker exec -it cf-cli bash`  I got error :`Error: No such container: cf-cli`

Answer (score 0):

If I correcly understand you just need

```
docker exec -it <runningcontainername> bash
```

Comment: HI, how can I find the container name ? I've the image name and the image id

Comment: when I run docker ps I see other running containers why I dont see `cf-cli` any idea ?

Comment: Oh, i think, i understand. You wanna go into image and change it without running it. You can't